# Layout of Janusgraph backend tables

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph

I am using JanusGraph with Cassandra as its storage backend. Its a fairly large graph with over 70 million vertices. What is the best way to get a list of all the vertex IDs. The query g.V() will take a long time to return. 
Is there a way I can pull out this data (all vertex IDs and if possible all edge IDs) directly from the Cassandra tables. I couldn't figure out how the data is stored. Can anybody help me please, or is there any clear documentation on how data is laid out in the backend tables.

Answer (score 2):

The way JanusGraph data is stored in Cassandra is documented at https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/data-model/ but if you use CQL or Nodetool to look at the tables created you will see the data is stored as blobs. I think the only way to get IDs is using Gremlin.